# Procedimiento en sql server para anonimizar datos

Tags: sql

Estoy realizando un procedimiento con el que alterar los datos de cada registro de un campo y de esta forma anonimizarlos.

Para ello estoy introduciendo dos parámetros (nombre de la tabla y el campo) y los quiero usar en consultas dinámicas. A continuación les dejo el código:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpsertAnonimizar]

   @svNombreTabla NVARCHAR(50),
   @svCampo NVARCHAR(100)

as
begin
    declare @svSql NVARCHAR(2000)
        
    begin try

        -- Sentencia update para modificar los campos y así anonimizar los datos
        if (@svCampo like '%mail%') 
        or (@svCampo like '%email%') 
        or (@svCampo like '%correo%')
        begin
            SET @svSql = 'UPDATE ' + @svNombreTabla + ' SET ' + @svCampo + ' = ''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(left(@svCampo, charindex('@', @svCampo)-1),'a',''),'e','a'),'o','x') + 
            RIGHT(@svCampo, LEN(@svCampo) - CHARINDEX('@', @svCampo)+1) + ''''
        end
    else
        begin
            SET @svSql = 'UPDATE ' + @svNombreTabla + ' SET ' + @svCampo + ' = ''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@svCampo,'a',''),'e','a'),'o','x') + ''''
        end
        
        -- Ejecución de la sentencia
        EXEC sp_executesql @svSql
        --PRINT @svSql

    end try
```

El error que obtengo al ejecutarlo es el siguiente:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

De esta información deduzco que no me está cogiendo los datos de los registros.

Agradezco de antemano todo tipo de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Podrías pegas la query dinámica, que te da la sentencia print que tienes comentada, así se puede saber que pasas en los parámetros, y que es lo que se ha montado sin tener que adivinarlo.

Comment: El error es de sintaxis, no de los datos. Probablemente, porque el parámetro @svCampo no contenga una arroba y charindex no te devuelva una posición.

Comment: Los parámetros que le paso son el nombre de la tabla y el nombre del campo. El nombre del campo es "email" y entiendo que me está cogiendo literalmente "email" en lugar de los email de cada usuario y por este motivo no aparecen las @

Comment: No. El problema es que la sentencia dinámica, no a lo que le estás haciendo el left de la columna. Le estás haciendo un left al contenido de la variable @svCampo, que dices que tiene 'email', y la parte izquierda de "email" - la primera ocurrencia de arroba..... no hay ocurrencias en el contenido de la variable svCampo.... por eso te da error de sintaxis.

Comment: Toda esa parte de la update, ya que la columna es "inyectada", tienes que tenerla entre apóstrofes....porque es dinámica en función de los datos. Al vuelo que te sobra o falta algún apóstrofe

Comment: Algo así... tienes que continuarlo tú: SET @svSql = 'UPDATE ' + @svNombreTabla + ' SET ' + @svCampo + ' = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(left('+@svCampo +`', charindex('@',

Comment: Gracias @Javifer2 por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te has confundido, principalmente con el tema de las comillas, además de la variable con el nombre del campo.

Es mejor simplificar el problema, resolverlo primero, y luego ir agregándole complejidad.

Por lo mismo, en lugar de un Stored procedure, te sugiero utilizar un simple bloque de código (que puedes ejecutar directamente en el SSMS con F5, para probar tu idea, y ya cuando esté de acuerdo a lo que buscas, lo *empacas* dentro de un procedimiento almacenado.

No olvides que estás formando una cadena de texto que debe contener una sentencia válida. Por lo mismo, si quieres que esa cadena tenga un apóstrofe, debes colocarlo doble cuando estás asignando el valor a la variable.

Es decir, si yo quiero que mi cadena contenga `campo = 'hola'`, entonces yo le asigno

```
@Variable = 'campo = ''hola''';
```

Luego, si el nombre del campo lo tengo en una variable y quiero que aparezca dentro de la cadena, entonces debo terminar la cadena y concatenarle la variable donde lo tengo, por ejemplo, si quiero que contenga `set campo = 'hola'`

```
@Variable = 'set ' + @NombreCampo + ' = ''hola''';
```

Si ves, estoy concatenando 3 piezas, la cadena `'set '`, la variable `@NombreCampo` y la cadena `' = ''hola'''`. Cada una de las constantes es una cadenas totalmente independiente.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, creo que buscas algo como lo siguiente:

```
declare @svNombreTabla NVARCHAR(50) = 'Tabla';
declare @svCampo NVARCHAR(100) = 'emailPersonal';

declare @svSql NVARCHAR(2000);
        
if    (@svCampo like '%mail%') 
   or (@svCampo like '%email%') 
   or (@svCampo like '%correo%')
  SET @svSql = 'UPDATE ' + @svNombreTabla + ' SET ' + @svCampo + ' = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(left(' + @svCampo + ', charindex(''@'', ' + @svCampo + ')-1),''a'',''''),''e'',''a''),''o'',''x'') + RIGHT(' + @svCampo + ', LEN(' + @svCampo + ') - CHARINDEX(''@'', ' + @svCampo + ')+1)';
else
  SET @svSql = 'UPDATE ' + @svNombreTabla + ' SET ' + @svCampo + ' = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' + @svCampo + ',''a'',''''''),''e'',''a''),''o'',''x'')';
        
PRINT @svSql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @svSql;
```

He cambiado la ejecución directa por un `print`, para primero poder observar si la cadena de SQL luce bien, y si todo luce como esperas, descomenta el `EXEC` y ve si se ejecuta sin problemas.

Yo me he concentrado en explicar el problema y producir una sentencia base que corrige los problemas que tu estabas dejando, pero no la he probado, eso ya te queda a ti de ejercicio.

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias.